# Pyramid - Writing unittest for file upload form

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, pyramid

I'm strugling with creating unittests for function in charge of uploading pictures recieved from a form on a page.

Main problem is that I can't figure out how to add picture to post parameters of a dummy request and as such pass it to function.

Here is code I'm trying to test.

Thanks

```
@view_config(route_name='profile_pic')
def profilePictureUpload(request):
 if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
    #max picture size is 700kb
    form = Form(request, schema=PictureUpload)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        upload_directory = 'filesystem_path'
        upload = request.POST.get('profile')
        saved_file = str(upload_directory) + str(upload.filename)

        perm_file = open(saved_file, 'wb')
        shutil.copyfileobj(upload.file, perm_file)

        upload.file.close()
        perm_file.close()

    else:
        log.info(form.errors)
 redirect_url = route_url('profile', request)
 return HTTPFound(location=redirect_url)
```

Answer (score 10):

It's really bad practice (and a potential security hole) to actually create a file on your filesystem with the a name supplied by the client (`upload.filename`).

With that out of the way, I see in your code you call `request.params`, `request.POST.get('profile')`, `upload.file` and `upload.filename`. We can mock all of these out, ultimately providing a StringIO object for `upload.file`.

```
class MockCGIFieldStorage(object):
    pass

upload = MockCGIFieldStorage()
upload.file = StringIO('foo')
upload.filename = 'foo.html'

request = DummyRequest(post={'profile': upload, 'form.submitted': '1'})

response = profilePictureUpload(request)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and pointing out to bad practice in my code.
I'll be sure to fix it.